# Using functions for binding element class names in Ember templates?

Tags: ember.js

When I have a template similar to:

```
{{#view App,NavItemView}}
<li {{bindAttr class="isActive:active"}}>Item 1</li>
{{/view}}
```

And a view of

```
App.NavItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  isActive: function() {
    return false;
  }
});
```

The rendered template will always render the class of 'active' on the `li` element. So based upon this it doesn't seem possible to have a conditional class set?

Ideally I would like the class of the li element to be turned on and off based upon the result of the function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use computed properties for this sort of thing.

```
App.NavItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  isActive: function() {
    return false;
  }.property()
});
```

Check out the [computed properties guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) for more details.